# ERROR: Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataLista'. Remove one definition.

Tags: c#, asp.net

What do I need to do when I see this error:( Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataLista'. Remove one definition.)

My code is below:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\upload\\";
    string[] list = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);     
        var listone = from filename in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path) select string.Format("upload/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename));     
        DataLista.DataSource = listone;
        DataLista.DataBind();//This line gives error
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your front-end code for the `DataLista` as well? It looks to me like you might be calling a DataSourceID on the front-end.

Comment: This is one of the clearest error messages I've seen in a long time. In what way it could have been improved so that you would realise what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the DataSourceID from the aspx.

You only use the DataSourceID if you're using a SqlDataSource or ObjectDataSource control for your binding.